# Reledmac: Numbering only a quote

Tags: quoting, reledmac

The reledmac documentation (section 17) tells us (after mentioning modifications to the `quote` and `quotation` environments that the package makes):

> You must open any quotation environments inside a \pstart ... \pend
>   block, not outside. A quotation environment MUST NOT be opened
>   immediately after a \pstart and MUST NOT be closed immediately before
>   a \pend.

What do I do if this is exactly what I require, i.e. if I need line numbering and a critical apparatus only for an indented quote?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{reledmac}
\setcounter{firstlinenum}{1}
\setcounter{linenumincrement}{1}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\beginnumbering
\pstart
\begin{quote}
\lipsum[2]
\end{quote}
\pend
\endnumbering

\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Apparently the last line number is in the wrong place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compatibility with quotation was added as I started to maintain ledmac. Today I won't do it in the same way. Maybe you could open an issue for an improvment of this feature.

Before that, you can use an hack, patching the command in your particular pstart.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{reledmac}
\setcounter{firstlinenum}{1}
\setcounter{linenumincrement}{1}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\beginnumbering
\pstart
\patchcmd{\endquote}{\vskip\topsep}{\relax}{}{}
\begin{quote}
\lipsum[2]
\end{quote}

\pend
\endnumbering

\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. I've opened an issue, https://github.com/maieul/ledmac/issues/756 .  I'm afraid your hack doesn't work for me in my example, I see no difference in the resulting pdf.

Comment: I have modified the example, to be sur you will see the good code. You must to make many run to get the good result, but, at Least on my computer, it works well.

Comment: No, even just copying your entire code above I just get the same result with the last line number being printed in the wrong place.

Comment: What? Here what I obtain as pdf. If you obtain something else, please send me directly an email.

Comment: https://drive.switch.ch/index.php/s/fwnqHdm3DJqWIQY

Comment: I just sent you an email with my files.

Comment: I made a typo in my command. Now it should be ok.